# Postegre sql update statement quotes issue

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Im attempting to update a last access time in my database the problem im having is that im using postgres sql and for the strings I must use double quotes inside of single quotes, however this is throwing off the statement, is there a way to get around this

```
$sql= "UPDATE users SET last_access=' .date("Y-M-D", time ()).' WHERE login_id= '" .$login. "'";
pg_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.** Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Comment: indeed, I want a login named `foo'; delete from users` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql= "UPDATE users SET last_access='"
    .date("Y-m-d", time ()).
    "' WHERE login_id= '$login'";
```

or easier and cleaner using Postgresql's date:

```
$sql= "UPDATE users SET last_access = current_date WHERE login_id= '$login'";
```